# What's the most efficient way to do a case-insensitive like expression?

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

In **Pervasive v13**, is there a "more performant" way to perform a **case-insensitive** [like expression](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/sqlref/sqlref.LIKE.htm) than is shown below?

```
select * from table_name
where upper(field_name) like '%TEST%'
```

The UPPER function above has performance cost that I'd like to avoid.

I disagree with those who say that the performance-overhead of UPPER is minor; it is doubling the execution time compared to the exact same query without UPPER.

**Background:**

I was very satisfied with the execution time of this wildcard-like-expression until I realized the result set was missing records due to mismatched capitalization.

Then, I implemented the UPPER technique (above). This achieved including those missing records, but it doubled the execution time of my query.

This UPPER technique, for case-insensitive comparison, seems outlandishly intensive to me at even a conceptual level. Instead of changing a field's case, for **every** record in a large database table, I'm hoping that the SQL standard provides some type of syntactical flag that modifies the like-expression's behavior regarding case-sensitivity.

From there, behind the scenes, the database engine could generate a compiled regular expression (or some other optimized case-insensitive evaluator) that could well outperform this UPPER technique. This seems like a possibility that might exist.

However, I must admit, at some level there still must be a conversion to make the letter-comparisons. And perhaps, this UPPER technique is no worse than any other method that might achieve the same result set.

Regardless, I'm posting this question in hopes someone might reveal a more performant syntax I'm unaware of.

Comment: Store the upper case version of your field in the table, but I cannot imagine that the `upper` function hits the execution time so much more than the `like` already does.

Comment: I'm aware of that technique, but I'm hoping for an answer that doesn't require schema modification or adding additional tables. The UPPER keyword is indeed adding seconds to the execution time when compared to the same search without it.

Comment: @LonnieBest . . . There is no performance to be gained.  `LIKE` does not (generally) use indexes if the pattern starts with a wildcard.  The conversion to upper case is minor overhead compared to reading the data.

Comment: I've edited my question to express my disagreement with those claiming UPPER overhead is minor.

Comment: UPPER overhead may not be minor, but not returning all true matches is far from minor.  If it's that important to the client(s) I'd strongly suggest altering the schema.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `UPPER`, when you define your table using `CASE`.

> The CASE keyword causes PSQL to ignore case when evaluating
> restriction clauses involving a string column. CASE can be specified
> as a column attribute in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement, or
> in an ORDER BY clause of a SELECT statement.

(see: https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/sqlref%2Fsqlref.CASE_(string).htm )

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (field_name VARCHAR(100) CASE)
```

Comment: I'm typically dealing with tables whose schemas were defined many years ago, having gigabytes of data already in them, and that have closed source applications depending upon those exact schemas. Therefore, modifying the schema using the `case` keyword may cause unforeseen ramifications (if the closed source application relies upon the case sensitive aspects of the current design) . Still, what you've posted is good to know during the database design phase of an application's lifecycle. Thanks.